# Can't draw the polygons in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to make a markdown map in R with Leaflet and I am trying to add a layer with polygons loaded in geoJSON format, when I run the code it does not give me any error but it does not draw the polygons I need, could you help me or tell me what is the error, please.

```
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)

url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/migueeel14/map/main/campos_prueba.geojson"
geojson <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url)
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(lng = -92.9303, lat = 17.9869, zoom = 8) %>%
  addGeoJSON(geojson)
```

Comment: Your geojson seems to be invalid, specifically it appears to violate the "right-hand-rule" (meaning that the area enclosed by a polygon must be to your right when walking along the polygon in the direction specified by the sequence of vertices. I tried with this online validator: https://geojsonlint.com/ For details and links how to fix the issue, see e.g. https://dev.to/rodreegez/geojson-right-hand-rule-2idk